# How to remove index.php from URLs in Kohana 3.1

Tags: kohana, url-routing

Currently, using Kohana 3.1, I can access my controllers using:

http://localhost/kohana/index.php/admin

However, I would like to access them without the "index.php" in the middle, as in:

http://localhost/kohana/admin

How can I do that? Do I need to change my .htaccess file or some config option?

I'm using the .htaccess provided with Kohana:

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /

# Protect hidden files from being viewed

    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All


# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the RewriteBase directive to where the application is. Yours would be:

```
# Installation directory
RewriteBase /kohana/
```

Also make sure you have the correct `base_url` in your bootstrap.

Comment: Perfect! Anyone on localhost should note that "localhost" isn't required in base_url or the htaccess. (kohana 3.2 for me)

Answer (score 6):

However, if you use `Rewritebase /kohana/`, you will still get `index.php` in the url. 
I'm using Kohana 3, so I go to `bootstrap.php` and change this:

```
Kohana::init(array(
    'base_url'   => '/',
    'index_file' => '',
));
```

Answer (score 1):

On some website I saw .htaccess suggestion:

```
# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php?kohana_uri=$0 [PT,L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you miss **kohaha** folder.
It should be like this:
Kohana::init(array(
    'base_url'   => '/kohana/',
    'index_file' => '',
));

Answer (score 0):

Turn on URL rewriting by adding the following code:

In .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
# Installation directory
RewriteBase /
```

In Bootstrap:

```
Kohana::init(array( 'base_url' => '', 'index_file' => '' ));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `'index_file' => FALSE` in bootstrap.php

Source : http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/kohana/tutorials/clean-urls